# How to return string that contains string/int variables

Tags: c++, string

For example, if I have this little function:

```
string lw(int a, int b) {    
    return "lw $" + a + "0($" + b + ")\n";
}
```

....and make the call `lw(1,2)` in my main function I want it to return `"lw $1, 0($2)"`.

But I keep getting an error: `invalid operands of types ‘const char*’ and ‘const char [11]’ to binary ‘operator+’`

What am I doing wrong?  I pretty much copied an example from class, and changed it to suit my function.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are trying to concatenate integers to strings, and C++ can't convert values of such different types. Your best bet is to use [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) to construct the result string:

```
#include <sstream>

// ...

string lw(int a, int b)
{
    ostringstream os;
    os << "lw $" << a << "0($" << b << ")\n";
    return os.str();
}
```

If you have [Boost](http://www.boost.org/), you can use [Boost.Lexical_cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html):

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

// ...

string lw(int a, int b)
{
    return
        string("lw $") +
        boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(a) +
        string("0($") +
        boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(b) +
        string(")\n");
}
```

---

And now with C++11 and later there is [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string):

```
string lw(int a, int b)
{
    return
        string("lw $") +
        std::to_string(a) +
        string("0($") +
        std::to_string(b) +
        string(")\n");
}
```

Comment: While your first sentence is correct, it also is completely irrelevant to the question since the OP is not concatenating `std::string`s.

Comment: @MarkB You're right. Updated answer to hopefully make it clearer.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <sstream>

string lw(int a, int b) {    
    std::string s;
    std::stringstream out;
    out << "lw $" << a << "0($" << b << ")" << endl;
    s = out.str();
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Works, but you're paying for a superfluous local copy of `out.str()`...why make that copy?  (Also I'll point out something that I didn't learn until recently, which is that in the general case `endl` isn't a synonym for `"\n"` - it flushes the stream.  So I've ceased "tidying" up uses of `"\n"` to use `endl`...)

Answer (score 2):

Use an ostringstream:

```
#include <sstream>
...
string lw(int a, int b) {
    std::ostringstream o;
    o << "lw $" << a << "0($" << b << ")\n";
    return o.str();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add string literals (like "hello") to integers. That is what compiler says to you. This is partial answer to your question. Please see *how* to accomplish what you want in another posts.

Comment: In fact you *can* add both `char` and `char*` to integers. It's just that most of the time that doesn't do at all what you want.

Comment: @MarkB I'll improve my answer.

Answer (score 0):

To understand this question, you have to know that in C++, string literals like `"lw $"` are treated as `const char[]` as inherited from the C language. However this means that you only get operators that are defined for arrays, or in this case the array-degrades-to-pointer case.

So what happens is you have a string literal, and then add an integer to it, creating a new pointer. Then you attempt to add *another* string literal which again degrades to `char*`. You can't add two pointers together, which then generates the error you're seeing.

You're trying to format integers into a string format with some delimiting text. In C++ the canonical way of doing that is with stringstreams:

```
#include <sstream>

string lw(int a, int b)
{
    std::ostringstream os;
    os << "lw $" << a << "0($" << b << ")\n";
    return os.str();
}
```